# Display data in datatable if that field value not available In table

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

In My Project There are 3 tables:- 1) projects 2) member 3) project_members.

Now When I fill project form and insert at that time on Add project form member list display from member table. But Now I add One more field "No Member Involved" Which is not available in member table.

So this field is not in member table. Now When I check The check box value insert in project_members table But at view time It is not display the data In data-table Because Of INNER JOIN of member and project_member.

How Should I display data Of NO MEMBER INVOLVED and other entries.

Comment: Are you talking about jQuery Datatables?

Comment: Yes jquery datatables.

Comment: I think the problem is in the query, not the datatable. Although how can anyone tell when you haven't posted any code? I'm guessing you need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.